# Initial form data from model - Django

Tags: django

I am trying to create an edit form for my model. I did not use a model form because depending on the model type, there are different forms that the user can use. (For example, one of the forms has a Tinymce widget, while the other doesn't.)

Is there any way of setting the initial data of a form (not a `ModelForm`) using a model?

I tried the following but getting an error:

```
b = get_object_or_404(Business, user=request.user)
form = f(initial = b)
```

where `f` is a subclass of `forms.Form`

The error I am getting is `AttributeError: 'Business' object has no attribute 'get'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial data needs to be a `dict` (or at least have a `dict`-like interface, which a Django model does not have).

You can construct a `dict` from your model using [`django.forms.models.model_to_dict`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L97):

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
b_as_dict = model_to_dict(b)
```

This is the same function Django's built in `ModelForm` class uses to set its initial data, and while you've specified that you don't want to use a `ModelForm` it may be more convenient to find some way of structuring your code that allows you to do so.

Comment: Yeah, I'll agree you should set up your own forms. You can set up a base form and then extend it with the different versions you need.

Answer (score 7):

There is a more direct way of using model data than dict. See sample in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/).

```
b = get_object_or_404(Business, user=request.user)
form = f(instance = b)
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted when it's actually the more correct one?

Comment: When the form is saved, the object will be modified. With the accepted answer, a new object with similar values will be created.

Comment: @velis It is not the correct one, as it is for a modelform, not a form.